# Selecting distinct entries based on count ratio in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following table in oracle SQL- 'reviews':

```
ID |   device   | rating  
---------------------  
1  |  nokia     | bad  
2  |  ericsson  | bad  
3  |  samsung   | good  
4  |  samsung   | good  
5  |  samsung   | bad  
6  |  motorola  | good  
7  |  motorola  | good  
8  |  motorola  | good  
9  |  nokia     | good
```

I need to select only those devices which have more than half of ratings being 'good' sorted alphabetically, the output should look like:

```
device
--------
motorola
samsung
```

I tried the following:

```
select device 
  from reviews
  where count(rating='good')/count(rating='bad')>0.5
  order by device desc
```

I know that my line 3 logic is where I am going wrong, but am unsure how to do the counts of the different ratings separately and then do the ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and a having clause:

```
select device
from reviews r
where rating in ('good', 'bad')
group by device
having sum(case when rating = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) > 0.5 * count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select device
from reviews 
group by device
having sum(case when rating = 'good' then 1 else -1 end) > 0
```

This assumes there are only 2 ratings: `'good'` and `'bad'` like your sample data.
 It will also work if there are other ratings too and you want to compare `'good'` against anything else.